# Renaming multiple files using parameter unix

Tags: unix, rename

I have a rename script below `rename.sh`. I want to introduce `a variable` such that I can pass a date argument when executing the script like
`./rename.sh 20151103`
 such that `20151103` replaces `20140306` in the script.

```
for f in *.CDR*; do
  echo mv "$f" "${f/-20140306/-0-20140306}"
done
```

Thinking of automating this as I don't want to manually edit the script each time i'm doing a rename. Any other method will be highly welcomed.

Comment: What is wrong with `TS=$1` and `mv "$f" "$TS"?

Comment: @GMichael That wouldn't do what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern="$1"

for f in *.CDR*; do
    echo mv "$f" "${f/-${pattern}/-0-${pattern}}"
done
```

Explanation:

- The `#!`-line says we're running this as a `bash` script.
- The script will populate the variables `$1`, `$2` etc. with the arguments handed to it on the command line.  These are called the *positional parameters* (`$0` usually holds the name of the script).
- We take `$1`, because we know that should contain the pattern we're replacing, and assign it to the variable `$pattern`. In much more complex scripts, here is where we would handle command line switches (with `getopts`, but that's an answer for another day).
- We quote `$1`, just because.  (It's good practice to quote user input, just to be sure no shell-globbing characters, such as `*` gets expanded).
- The rest is the script like you had from before, but with the string `20140306` replaced by `${pattern}`. I'm using `${pattern}` rather than `$pattern` here for readability only. In general, you need to use `${a}` rather than `$a` if you, for example, interpolate a string like `"${a}nospaceafter"`.

Then it should just be a matter of making the script executable before testing it:

```
$ chmod +x rename.sh
```

Comment: You totally killed it. I understand thanks. Let me sit down with it and i'm sure i'll have more questions to ask.

Comment: I created a directory `renamed` like you suggested earlier, there in are the files to be renamed and also the script. I run the script with `./rename.sh 20160611` and got a message `/usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. I think i'm missing something.

Comment: @oak This means that the first line of the script (`#!...`) has the wrong path to `bash` on your system. See with the `which bash` command what it should be and rewrite that line.

Comment: @oak It should probably be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Sure you are right. didn't notice that before. it worked. I have another question in mind but let me confirm first. I really like this. Thanks so much

Comment: Hmm, think i'm Ok for now. Is there a way you could track my subsequent posts? Would like your replies henceforth.

Comment: @oak I can obviously not promise anything, and there are others that are better than me. If I see questions that interest me, and that I can answer to, I investigate them, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one of the method you can consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1

for f in *.CDR*; do
  echo mv "$f" "${f/-$input/-0-$input}"
done
```